# ActiveX ComboBox_Change event falsely triggering a Compile Error: Variable not defined

Tags: vba, excel, activex

This is being triggered by my `Option Explicit` at the top of my module. When I open my workbook, my `cbSelectData_Change` event fires (for whatever reason), which then says my variable `cbStartDate` is not defined (i'll include the lines but it shouldn't be relevant:

```
topnum = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Pull").Columns(3).Find(What:=cbStartDate.Value, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
botnum = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Pull").Columns(3).Find(What:=cbEndDate.Value, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
```

`cbSelectData` is an ActiveX ComboBox containing a data category that charts populate off of. `cbStartDate` and `cbEndDate` are ActiveX ComboBoxes that alter the date range displayed on the chart x-axies.

I can confirm that I have a `cbStartDate` and a `cbEndDate` on my worksheet:

[image: img1]

In fact, when I just exit the debugger (twice) my file will work fine; I can freely change my `cbStartDate` and `cbEndDate` and my charts update as expected, and I never see the compile error again (until re-opening the file).

**My Suspicion:**

This has something to do with the instantiations of the ActiveX controls - while `cbSelectData` is loaded (and firing its `Change` event), it's not finding `cbStartDate` or `cbEndDate` because they're not loaded yet.

**What I need to do:**

I either need to stop my `cbSelectData_Change` event from firing when I open the file, or I need to force the loading of my `cbStartDate` and `cbEndDate` before this event fires. I've messed around with `Application.EnableEvents` to no avail - any insight to this would be appreciated.

Note: These have to be ActiveX controls for formatting purposes. I also know that I can remove my `Option Explicit` altogether, but I'd REALLY rather not...

Comment: I have noticed things like that in other workbooks as well when opening workbooks that have a workbook or worksheet event.

Comment: @Davesexcel It definitely seems to be because they're `ActiveX` controls - but there must be a better solution than removing `Option Explicit` and wrapping some lines in `On Error Resume Next/GoTo 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what broke it, but ActiveX controls *can* be flaky.

Try retrieving the object at run-time instead of compile-time:

```
Public Function FindActiveXControl(ByVal sh As Worksheet, ByVal name As String) As Object

    Dim objects As OLEObjects
    Set objects = sh.OLEObjects

    On Error Resume Next
        Dim oleControl As OLEObject
        Set oleControl = objects.Item(name)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not oleControl Is Nothing Then Set FindActiveXControl = oleControl.Object

End Function
```

Now you can work with locals, and handle the weird case where the control wouldn't be found:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = Me

Dim startDateControl As MSForms.ComboBox
Set startDateControl = FindActiveXControl(sheet, "cbStartDate")
If Not startDateControl Is Nothing Then
    topnum = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Pull").Columns(3).Find(What:=startDateControl.Value, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
End If

Dim endDateControl As MSForms.ComboBox
Set endDateControl = FindActiveXControl(sheet, "cbEndDate")
If Not endDateControl Is Nothing Then
    botnum = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Pull").Columns(3).Find(What:=endDateControl.Value, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
End If
```

Comment: Looks like I'm missing a reference - Unable to get the Object property of the OLEObject class at `Set FindActiveXControl = oleControl.Object` in your UDF.

Comment: This might very well explain the compile error you're getting. Verify that you have `OLE Automation` (stdole2.tlb) referenced (it should be referenced by default... it is on a blank Excel workbook here)

Comment: Ahh! Which library should I add? I do have `OLE Automation` checked off.

Comment: hmm, something is definitely corrupt somewhere then.

Comment: Oh boy... Well for now I removed `Option Explicit` and wrapped my `topnum` and `botnum` lines with `On Error Resume Next/Go To 0`, giving them default values in case it fails - do you think this is a viable solution? I really hate the band-aid fix.

Comment: I'd try deleting and re-creating the ActiveX control. Failing that, deleting and re-creating the whole worksheet. The function *does* work on a fresh new empty project, right? It *you* can't get `oleControl.Object`, neither can VBA...

Comment: So I tested it on a brand new workbook and it said "invalid use of "Me" property". I changed the Me to the worksheet's name and it worked fine. I went back to my original workbook and changed the Me to my sheet's name, and it looks to be working!

Comment: Gah, that's me adapting tested/working code to the SO answer box without testing - sorry about that.

Comment: Ahh wait, re-opening a second time and it's failing on the `Set FindActiveXControl = oleControl.Object` line again... it's so inconsistent...

Comment: This has all looks of a corrupt OLE object IMO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174965/discussion-between-dwirony-and-mathieu-guindon).

Comment: Scratch that - I cannot reproduce the bug, and the problem is back. Looks to be something corrupted with my ActiveX files - I'll have to reinstall or something. Thanks though!

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you
refer to an ActiveX ComboBox using the OLEObjects property:

```
topnum = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Pull").Columns(3).Find(What:=Worksheets("DataPull").OLEObjects("cbStartDate").Object.Value, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
```